# How to remove sprites out of group, outside of the class: Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

```
#Importing Modules
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random

#All pygame stuff under here
pg.init()

#Font definitions
backFont = pg.font.SysFont("monospace",40)
titleFont = pg.font.SysFont("garamond", 100)
cipherFont = pg.font.SysFont("garamond", 50)
buttonFont = pg.font.SysFont("garamond", 25)
bigFont = pg.font.SysFont("garamond",100)
Font = pg.font.SysFont(None,32)
inputFont = pg.font.SysFont('consola', 35)
errorFont = pg.font.SysFont('tahoma',20)
diagramFont = pg.font.SysFont('courier new',25)

#Colour definitions
BackGray = pg.Color('gray60')
screenGray = pg.Color('gray80')
buttonGray2 = pg.Color('gray50')
textColour = pg.Color('navy')

#Screen size set
screen = pg.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

class Button(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, width, height, colour, enabled):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        txt = buttonFont.render(text, True, textColour)
        txtRect = txt.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        self.image.blit(txt, txtRect)
        self.rect.topleft = x, y
        self.enabled = enabled

    def isPressed(self, event):
        if self.enabled == True:
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    return True
        return False

def Function():
    background = pg.Surface(screen.get_size())

    background.fill(screenGray)

    Button1 = Button('Encrypt',100,100,125,50,buttonGray2,True)
    Button2 = Button('Decrypt',100,200,125,50,buttonGray2,True)

    buttonsGroup = pg.sprite.Group(Button1,Button2)

    ACTIONPRINT = False
    Active1 = False

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif Button1.isPressed(event):
                print("1")
                Active1 = True
            elif Button2.isPressed(event):
                print("2")

        if Active1 == True:
            ACTIONPRINT = True
            buttonsGroup = pg.sprite.Sprite.remove(Button2)

        screen.blit(background,(0,0))
        buttonsGroup.draw(screen)
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

Function()
```

Above is the code for the class of Buttons, and a simple function that runs two buttons. What I'd like to do is remove one of the buttons, when one is pressed, which are set as sprites. When the button is removed from the group, I believe it should disappear from the screen, after one is pressed.

The above code at the minute returns an error saying that there is an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'`. However, in another program, when it did work, it said that in the `Sprite.remove` method, the parameters must be a sequence and not a button - what does this mean?

I have looked online, and all the removing sprites examples are inside a class. Does that mean that the only way for this to work is by changing the class?

Or can sprites still be removed from outside the class, and if so how is it done?

Any other methods are welcome to

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sprite.Group.remove`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.remove) doesn't return anything, it removes the sprite from the group that calls it, so instead of:

```
buttonsGroup = pg.sprite.Sprite.remove(Button2)
```

Try:

```
buttonsGroup.remove(Button2)
```